# SQL Server concatenate ignore null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I am currently working on a query which join multiple columns in to 1 string with comma (,) as a separator between each other. I'm unable to figure out how to deal with null values.

```
DECLARE 
    @item1 nvarchar(max) = 'a',
    @item2 nvarchar(max) = 'b',
    @item3 nvarchar(max) = 'c'

SELECT CONCAT(
    ISNULL(NULLIF(@item1, '') + ', ', ''), 
    ISNULL(NULLIF(@item2, '') + ', ', ''), 
    ISNULL(NULLIF(@item3, ''), '')
)

--@item1 = 'a', @item2 = 'b', @item3 = 'c'
--Output : a, b, c

--@item1 = 'a', @item2 = NULL, @item3 = 'c'
--Output : a, c

--@item1 = NULL, @item2 = 'b', @item3 = 'c'
--Output : b, c
```

With the code above it works well when `@item1` or `@item2` even both are NULL value, but there is a problem if `@item3` is NULL value, it will have an extra comma(,) at the end,

```
--@item1 = 'a', @item2 = 'b', @item3 = NULL
--Output : a, b,

--@item1 = 'a', @item2 = NULL, @item3 = NULL
--Output : a,
```

I know this is because I hard coded the comma(,) on the `NULLIF` statement for `@item1` and `@item2`, but I can't figure out there is any other better way to do this.

Any advise or a better solution for this problem?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/93273211

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `STUFF` method is probably the better option here:

```
STUFF(CONCAT(',' + NULLIF(@item1, ''),',' + NULLIF(@item2, ''),',' + NULLIF(@item3, '')),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler than `STUFF`, use `CONCAT_WS`:

```
CONCAT_WS(', ', NULLIF(@item1,''), NULLIF(@item2,''), NULLIF(@item3,''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use, the concat operator,
for the first variable don't pass concat separator, from second variable onwards pass the concat variable (separator) before variable...

```
declare @a varchar(10)='a'
declare @b varchar(10)='b'
declare @c varchar(10)=null
select isnull(@a,'')+isnull(','+@b,'')+isnull(','+@c,'')
```

Comment: This doesn't return the result the OP wants if any of the values have the value `''` or `NULL`.