Query to create new data column with alphabetical concatenating the data
I'm not trying to eliminate the null values from table, so it's not duplicate of link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205266/sql-server-concatenate-ignore-null-value][1]
How can I get result like OUTPUT table to be queried from original table?
I want to set the column values in alphabetical order and concatenate them as new column value.
Original table:
clsID   stdID   c1      c2      c3      
---------------------------------------
cls1    10      HE      HQ      UA      
cls1    11      HQ      H1      UA      

cls2    20      HG      AB      NULL    
cls2    21      H2      HQ      UA      
cls2    22      NULL    HQ      UA      

cls3    30      HG      AB      NULL    
cls3    31      HQ      GH      UA      
cls3    32      NULL    HQ      UA      
cls3    33      NULL    null    null    

In my output, I need to concatenate the columns stdId, c1, c2, c3, c4 and keep the new value as new column concatenatedvalue.
Resulting table:
clsID   concatenatedvalue   stdID   c1      c2      c3      
-----------------------------------------------------------
cls1    10-HE-HQ-UA         10      HE      HQ      UA      
cls1    11-H1-HQ-UA         11      HQ      H1      UA      

cls2    20-AB-HG            20      HG      AB      NULL    
cls2    21-H2-HQ-UA         21      H2      HQ      UA      
cls2    22-HQ-UA            22      NULL    HQ      UA      

cls3    30-AB-HG            30      HG      AB      NULL    
cls3    31-GH-HQ-UA         31      HQ      GH      UA      
cls3    32-HQ-UA            32      NULL    HQ      UA      
cls3    33                  33      NULL    null    null    


DO NOT tag spam. Pick one database tag.

And show us your current query attempt.

It would also be better to have a sample row where your C4 value is not null. Otherwise, why bother having the C4 column?

@Isolated I deleted the c4 column

I'm voting to reopen the question because you are also asking for alphabetical concatenation.

@AdrianKlaver I have tagged to correct category of audience

@jarlh I'm a beginner to SQL, I tried pivot table method, coalesce methods, but those are not giving me expected results. So I'm kind of stuck how can I get this requirement achieve. thanks in advance.

@SoftwareEnginner ppsssssst: fun fact: there is never any reason to ever use PIVOT, ever.

Since you need the concatenated value to be alphabetized, it would help to unpivot your data first and then string_agg() your data back together.
WITH unioncte (
   SELECT clsid, stdid,  c1 as col from table
   union
   SELECT clsid, stdid, c2 from table
   union 
   SELECT clsID, stdID, c3 from table
)
SELECT unioncte.clsid, 
   CONCAT(stdID, STRING_AGG(col, '-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col) as concatinatedvalue,
   unioncte.stdid,
   t1.c1, 
   t1.c2,
   t1.c3
FROM unioncte
   INNER JOIN table as t1 
      ON unioncte.clsid = t1.clsid 
         AND unioncte.stdid = t1.stdid
GROUP BY clsid, stdid, c1, c2, c3


This solution uses the UNPIVOT function within the CTE. The rest is similar and also using string_agg and within group to order your values.
with cte as (
  select clsID, stdID, cols, vals
  from (
   select clsID, stdID, c1, c2, c3 
     from tableA
   ) a
  unpivot
  (vals for cols in (c1, c2, c3)
   ) as unpvt
)
select 
  a.clsID, 
  case 
   when a.c1 is null and a.c2 is null and a.c3 is null then cast(a.stdID as varchar)
   else concat(a.stdID, '-', string_agg(c.vals, '-') within group (order by c.vals)) 
  end as concat_value, 
  a.stdID, a.c1, a.c2, a.c3
from tableA a
left join cte c
  on a.clsID = c.clsID
 and a.stdID = c.stdID
group by a.clsID, a.stdID, a.c1, a.c2, a.c3
order by 1,3




clsID
concat_value
stdID
c1
c2
c3




cls1
10-HE-HQ-UA
10
HE
HQ
UA


cls1
11-H1-HQ-UA
11
HQ
H1
UA


cls2
20-AB-HG
20
HG
AB
null


cls2
21-H2-HQ-UA
21
H2
HQ
UA


cls2
22-HQ-UA
22
null
HQ
UA


cls3
30-AB-HG
30
HG
AB
null


cls3
31-GH-HQ-UA
31
HQ
GH
UA


cls3
32-HQ-UA
32
null
HQ
UA


cls3
33
33
null
null
null



fiddle
